# Añadir datos a una columna nueva en un dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Hola tengo un problema tengo un data set como este:

[image: Dataset]

Tengo que crear la columna nueva y en ella almacenar el valor de la columna marcaTemp. Para seleccionar que valor escoger, tengo la condición de que el valor elegido es el que cumple la con que la primera vez que Factor = T pasa a F sea el valor de la marca, el cual debería seleccionarse para la nueva columna, como podéis ver en el ejemplo.

He probado esto:

```
valor = T
for row in df.iterator():
     if(valor != row["Factor"]):
         df["ColumnaNueva"] = row["MarcaTemp"]
```

Edito:

Lo que indica el compañero esta bien, el resultado que busco es este:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"Jugador":("P1","P1","P1","P1","P2","P2","P2","P2"),
                   "Factor": ("T", "T", "F", "F","T", "T", "T", "F"),
                   "MarcaTemp": (1, 2, 3, 4,5,6,7,8),
                  "ColumnaNueva":(3,3,3,3,8,8,8,8)}
                  )
df
```

He intentado hacer algo asi:

```
for name, group in df.groupby('leg'): 
    if groundVar != group["ground"]:
```

para luego meter lo que quiero que haga que es añadir a la columna el valor,pero sin éxito...

[image: Resultado Buscado]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No tienes que iterar manualmente sobre el DataFrame, usa simplemente un filtro boleano para conocer las filas en las que `Factor` es `"F"` y luego simplemente selecciona la primera:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np


df = pd.DataFrame({"Factor": ("T", "T", "F", "F"),
                   "MarcaTemp": (1, 2, 3, 4)}
                  )
query = df[df.Factor == "F"]
df["ColumnaNueva"] = np.nan if query.empty else query.iloc[0].MarcaTemp
```

> ```
> >>> df
>
>   Factor  MarcaTemp  ColumnaNueva
> 0      T          1             3
> 1      T          2             3
> 2      F          3             3
> 3      F          4             3
> ```

Si se diera el caso que `T` nunca pasara a `F` la columna quedaría con valor `NaN`, pero puedes elegir el valor por defecto que desees si este caso se pude dar.

Comment: Vale esta genial @FJSevilla , y si tuviera que moverme entre grupos? Con eso me refiero imagina que tenemos Jugador1 y este tiene sus marcas, y luego jugador2 que tendra sus marcas tambien, ambos tendran valores diferentes de ColumnaNueva, perdona que te haga la pregunta por aqui pero no se como iterar muy bien entre ellos, he probado con un groupby y luego hacerlo, pero por lo visto no es muy compatible!